# how to write domain force on two many2many fields in record rules

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I want to write domain force in record rule for many2many fields in xml

I have internal team ,and I want to do user can see only those project in which team it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply domain in many2many field

```
<field name="project_id" widget="many2many_tags" domain="[('in_team', '=', True)]"/>
```